# Formatting time on a Y axis in ggplott2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have the following code:

```
file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "WaterLevel", "Grade1", "Symbol1", 
                     "QAQC-1", "DischargeDebit", "Grade2", "Symbol2", 
                     "QAQC-2")

subds <- subset(skdat, ID=='05AH050')
subds$datetime1 <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(subds$Date))
class(data$datetime1)


subds[1:10, ]
ggplot(aes(x = datetime1, y = "WaterLevel"), data = subds) + geom_line()
```

Is there a way I can show just the time in 2 hr intervals on the Y axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear what do you mean by "time in 2 hr intervals on the Y axis" because time is on the x-axis. Here is an example to change the breaks to 2 hours on the x-axis. The `datetime1` need to be in `POSIXct` class.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

subds$datetime1 <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date)

ggplot(aes(x = datetime1, y = WaterLevel), data = subds) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"),
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image]